# Best practice to deploy dacpac along asp.net core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, web-deployment, dacpac

I am trying out to figure what would be the best way to deploy a dacpac along an asp.net core application.

Its an application that we provide to external users for download as an on-premise version to be installed in Azure, as such I am trying to make it a smooth as possible

For now now I was planning to use DacFx and in the asp.net core startup code to check the database based on the connectionstring and if version are lower startup the execution of the package against the DB directly in the code but the problem is that DacFx is not yet, at time of writing, supported on .net core and its not planned for still several month ahead.

We can of course provide some script or short documentation on how to use the SqlPackage to deploy or even through the sql user interface but this would require 2 steps from him first install the asp.net core stuff and then manually deploy the dacpac we would prefer to have a straighforward solution for the end user to let him deploy the app as easily as possible. Is there any other solution to we overlooked ?

thanks a lot